# Use Raspberry Pi as Ethernet-to-HDMI converter

Tags: windows, linux, display, raspberry-pi, converter

My laptop (running on Windows 11) has a HDMI port which is used to extend my desktop with a screen (as you would). I have another screen lying around and I would like to make it a third screen for my setup. The problem is that my laptop only has one single HDMI port.

I was wondering if I could use my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ as an Ethernet-to-HDMI converter. My idea is to connect the Rpi to my laptop via Ethernet and connect my monitor to the Rpi via HDMI.

I am thus looking for an app which would make my laptop act as the server, that would create an extension of my desktop and send it to the Rpi which would act as the client and display the video stream to my display via HDMI.

I have tested [spacedesk](https://www.spacedesk.net/) but it is too slow since it does not have a native application for linux and thus needs to run in the browser on this OS.

I would like to specify that I don't want to buy another product, I just want to know if this is possible with what I have at my disposal.

Comment: 1920×1080×24Bit×60/s = 2,4 GBit/s. You certainly don't want to play games. With 100 MBit/s on the RPi3, it will either have a slow refresh rate or compression artefacts or you display Office content only.

Comment: Okay, well I guess I would use it only to display my messaging or music app then